# Close statement object before starting a new with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm quite new at using prepared statements and is wondering if I should close the stmt_init() after each call or could I just keep it open?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("SELECT player_draws, player_turn, player_passes, swapped FROM ".$prefix."_gameplayer WHERE fk_game_id = ? AND fk_player_id = ?")){

    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $currgame, $playerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($udraws, $uturn, $upass, $uswaps);
    $stmt->fetch();

    echo $udraws.'-'.$uturn.'-'.$upass.'-'.$uswaps.'<br>';

    // Close statement object
    $stmt->close(); 

}

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("SELECT player_draws, player_turn, player_passes, swapped FROM ".$prefix."_gameplayer WHERE fk_game_id = ? AND fk_player_id != ?")){

    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $currgame, $playerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($odraws, $oturn, $opass, $oswaps);
    $stmt->fetch();

    echo $odraws.'-'.$oturn.'-'.$opass.'-'.$oswaps.'<br>';

    // Close statement object
    $stmt->close(); 

}
```

Is one of them better for the database considering calls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*...A prepared statement or a parameterized statement is used to execute the same statement repeatedly with high efficiency...*

**EDIT**
Since the queries are different each of them will need to be prepared separately but you should be able to reuse the $mysqli->stmt_init();

On a side note someone mentions this in the [comments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php):

*if you are repeating an statement in an loop using bind_param and so on inside it for a larger operation. i thougt id would be good to clean it with stmt->close. but it broke always with an error after aprox. 250 operations . As i tried it with  stmt->reset it worked for me.*

Comment: But in the first one I want to get data from WHERE fk_player_id = ? and in the second I want WHERE fk_player_id != ?. How can I put this in the same?

Comment: Sorry only saw that now, thought they were the same. You should be able to use the same $mysqli->stmt_init(); for both but you will need to re-prepare the second query.

Comment: Thanks :-) You have been at great help!